# .NET - Block main thread until there are any available threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a process where my main thread is reading a file and splitting it into parts.  Those parts then require further processing.  I would like to utilize any available threads so that the downstream processing is utilizing as much CPU (or as many cores) as possible.  I don't want to create an excessive backlog from the main thread, so I need the main thread to wait to add to the queue until there is another available thread.

I see many articles like [VB.NET 4.0: Looking to execute multiple threads, but wait until all threads are completed before resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827651/vb-net-4-0-looking-to-execute-multiple-threads-but-wait-until-all-threads-are), but they are waiting for **all threads to complete**, whereas I just need **any threads to be available**

Is this something I can tackle with the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), or should I be manually creating threads and monitoring a threadpool?

```
Using Reader As New StreamReader(FileName)
    Do
        CurrentBlockSize = Reader.ReadBlock(CurrentBuffer, 0, BufferSize)

        RunningBuffer &= New String(CurrentBuffer)

        If RunningBuffer.Contains(RowDelimiter) Then
            LineParts = RunningBuffer.Split(RowDelimiter)

            For I As Integer = 0 To LineParts.Count - 1
                If I < LineParts.Count - 1 Then

                    'Make synchronous call that blocks until' 
                    'another thread is available to process the line'
                    AddLineToTheProcessingQueue(CurrentLine)

                Else
                    RunningBuffer = LineParts(I)
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Loop While CurrentBlockSize = BufferSize
End Using
```

Comment: This is almost certainly wasted effort, this kind of code is almost always disk bound.  A simple check:  restart your machine and run the single threaded version.  If the CPU load on one core doesn't go over 50% then adding more threads cannot make it faster.

Comment: @HansPassant, the downstream work is going to involve processing and sending large amounts of data to a database over TCP/IP, which is probably going to be slower then the disk reads.  That's the part I want multi-threaded

Comment: Then pull, don't push the data.  Much like most programs do that read a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code into a new Console Application.

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    ' I just picked 6 randomly, not sure what is a good strategy for picking this number
    ' also, not sure what is the difference between a Worker Thread and a Completion thread
    Const MaxWorkerThreads As Integer = 6
    Const MaxCompletionPortThreads As Integer = 6

    Sub Main()

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxWorkerThreads, MaxCompletionPortThreads)

        Dim availableWorkerThreads As Integer
        Dim availableCompletionPortThreads As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To 100

            ' GetAvailableThreads returns results via output parameters
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(availableWorkerThreads, availableCompletionPortThreads)

            Dim tries As Integer = 0

            Do While (availableWorkerThreads = 0)
                ' this loop does not execute if there are available threads
                ' you may want to add a fail-safe to check "tries" in case the child threads get stuck
                tries += 1

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("waiting to start item {0}, attempt {1}, available threads: {2}, {3}", i, tries, availableWorkerThreads, availableCompletionPortThreads))

                ' failure to call Sleep will make your program unresponsive
                Thread.Sleep(1000)

                ' call GetAvailableThreads again for the next test at the top of the loop
                ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(availableWorkerThreads, availableCompletionPortThreads)
            Loop

            ' this is how you pass parameters to a thread created through QueueUserWorkItem
            Dim parameters As Object() = {i}
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf DoWork, parameters)
            ' According to MSDN, you must Sleep after calling QueueUserWorkItem, or else the current thread will just exit
            Thread.Sleep(500)

        Next

    End Sub

    Sub DoWork(parameters As Object())
        Dim itemNumber = parameters(0)
        Dim sleepLength = itemNumber * 1000
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Item: {0} - sleeping for {1} miliseconds.", itemNumber, sleepLength))
        Thread.Sleep(sleepLength)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Item: {0} - done sleeping.", itemNumber))
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly do you want to do this, but you can achieve something very similar by using [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) or a dataflow block with `BoundedCapacity` set.

For example, if you set the capacity to 1 and your consumers are busy at the moment, you won't be able to add a second item to the queue until one of the consumers finishes its current work and removes that item from the queue. And both versions give you a way to wait until you can add another item to the queue.

Comment: Yeah I started reading about TPL-Data Flow and the Bounded Capacity last night, very promising.  I'll report back after some testing.  Do you have any example code of a dataflow block with Bounded Capacity?

Comment: @TomHalladay You could look at [this set of tests](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Test/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/BoundedCapacityTest.cs) in mono's version of TDF.